# Не получается импортировать физику из Blender в Unity

Tags: unity3d, blender

Добрый день. Я создал проект в Blender с простой физикой, где шар на цепи разбивает кубы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все прекрасно работает, но при переносе модели в среду Unity ничего не происходит, просто статичная модель. Объясните мне, что я делаю не так!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Физика из блендера не импортируется. Только как анимация.

Comment: Не подскажешь как из физики сделать анимацию?! Или это как то по другому работает?